# Flutter How to apply search filter in a querysnapshot used in Listview builder

Tags: flutter, search, filter, snapshot

This is my firebase data request code
and this is my future builder based on the qn.docs
How to search within the snapshot and ListView.builder to use the filtered set.
previously I was using a Local List and used to search as on Itemchanged
thanks in advance for your guidance.
I am new to flutter. so please explain with an example

```
    Future <QuerySnapshot> getSpeakernames() async {
      QuerySnapshot qn =  await 
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('speakernames').orderBy('speakername').get();
      return qn;
    }

Center(
child: Container(
 child: ListView.builder(
   itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
       return ListTile(title: Text(data.get("speakername")),
              subtitle: Text(data.get("speakerdegree")), )



    onItemChanged(String value) {
        setState(() {
          data.get("speakername").
          newspeakernames = speakernames
              .where((string) => 
                 string.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
              .toList();
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ".Where" property of Firestore

like below

```
Future <QuerySnapshot> getSpeakernames() async {
QuerySnapshot qn =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('speakernames')
.where('speakername' , isEqualTo : SubramanianV).orderBy('speakername').get();

      return qn;
   
 }
```

Comment: but I want to filter the full list of speakers after the initial fetch. every search need not pull data from firestore. it is enough to filter the received data by the search text field.

Comment: Yes u can do that , by changing that 'speakername' to a String  , and giving that String value of the TextField and then using setState

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I actually needed is some sort of wild card search as and when I type. When I type 'ma' it should return Mahesh, mani, mark, etc. Even if the speaker's name is  Subramanian searching for 'ma' or 'man' or 'ubra' should return Subramanian which I feel is not available right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isGreaterThanOrEqualTo.

Example:

```
    class doctorName {
  getDoctorByName(String doctorName, String last) async {
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("Doctor")
        .where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: doctorName)
        .where("name", isLessThan: last)
        //.where("name", isEqualTo: doctorName)
        .getDocuments();
  }
}
```